# Sequelize, set column as foreign key to a table from another schema

Tags: foreign-keys, schema, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a table:

```
            queryInterface.createTable('MyTable', {
                id: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    autoIncrement: true
                },
               SomeTableId: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    references: { model: 'static.SomeTable', key: 'id'},
                    allowNull: false
                },

            }, t);
```

The problem is that this error is thrown, when I run the migration :

```
'Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: relation "static.SomeTable" does not exist'
```

So, basically, the question is:

*When I am creating a table in the **'public'** schema, how can I specify a foreign key column in that table, that references a table in the **'static'** schema.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, the right syntax is:

```
 queryInterface.createTable('MyTable', {
                id: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    autoIncrement: true
                },
               SomeTableId: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    references: { 
                        model: {
                            tableName: 'SomeTable', 
                            schema: 'static'
                        }
                        key: 'id'
                    },
                    allowNull: false
                },

            }, t);
```

And we are done, problem solved :)

Comment: Great one, good to know about that feature! Tried to find an answer for couple of minutes but glad you made it :)

Comment: You save my day! Thank u.

Comment: I got `ERROR: Failed to open the referenced table 'schema.table`. Do you know if there's any other setup required for this to work? Both schema and table exist